# Отредактированный вывод двумерного массива

Tags: php, массивы, циклы, вывод

Есть двумерный массив состоящий из цифр
`[[45, 16, 18, 72], [23, 8, 9, 36, 15, 36]]`

Хочу вывети его, при этом вывести так, как он выглядит в редакторе кода, вот так

`[[ 45 16 18 72 ], [ 23 8 9 36 15 36 ]]`

Для решения задачи использую цикл `for`. Пробовал и цикл `foreach`- не вышло, только такое выходило вывести `[[ 45 16 18 72 23 8 9 36 15 36 ]]`

Вот решение циклом `for`:

```
echo 'echo: $twoDimensionalArrays = [[ ';
                
for ($i = 0; $i < count($twoDimensionalArrays); $i++) {
                    
  for ($j = 0; $j < count($twoDimensionalArrays[$i]); $j++) {
                        
    if ($j == count($twoDimensionalArrays[0])) echo ' ], [ ';
      echo ' ' . $twoDimensionalArrays[$i][$j];
    }
                    
  }
                
}
                
echo ' ]];';
```

Выводится следующий результат

`echo: $twoDimensionalArrays = [[ 45 16 18 72 23 8 9 36 ], [ 15 36 ]];`

Как подправить код, чтоб выводило именно вот так?

`echo: $twoDimensionalArrays = [[ 45 16 18 72 ], [ 23 8 9 36 15 36 ]];`

Comment: а implode совсем использовать нельзя?

Comment: Функция `implode()` - объединяет элементы массива, например запятой. Это первое, что Google мне выдавал по запросу в поиске. Как применить к моему заданию, не понял, и пошел путем просто написать условие, при достижении которого выведутся две визуально разделяющие скобки '], ['. Сами элементы массива хотел просто разделить пробелами, без запятых

Comment: Ну то есть тебе непонятно значение слова "например", и вариант использовать прорбел для объединения ты не рассматривал?

Comment: Не подумайте, что решение нашел, и пошел фигней страдать, нет. Я увидел Ваш комментарий, и вернулся к строкам кода с выводом массива. Пытался применить, опять с помощью условия `if`, мне интересны различные варианта решений. `implode(' ', $array)` рассматриваю вариант, без `' ' . $array` - красивее будет, без миллиарда точек конкатенации

Comment: Пример или не пример, поздно, хотел посмотреть что выйдет. Кроме `Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments` - ничего не получил интересного

Comment: И действительно, если вызвать функцию с аргументами от балды, то не получится ничего интересного

Comment: Согласен, передать в функцию `implode(' ', $twoDimensionalArrays[$i][$j]);` вместо `echo ' ' . $twoDimensionalArrays[$i][$j];` плохая затея, массива там нет еще

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас какое-то непонятное условие `if ($j == count($twoDimensionalArrays[0]))`, которое тут вообще не должно проверяться. Следующий вариант будет верным:

```
<?php

$twoDimensionalArrays = [[45, 16, 18, 72], [23, 8, 9, 36, 15, 36]];

echo 'echo: $twoDimensionalArrays = [[';
                
for ($i = 0; $i < count($twoDimensionalArrays); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($twoDimensionalArrays[$i]); $j++) {
        echo ' ' . $twoDimensionalArrays[$i][$j];
    }
    if($i !== count($twoDimensionalArrays)-1) {
        echo ' ], [';
    }
                
}
                
echo ' ]];';
```

Comment: Это я хотел, чтоб когда `$j` будет равна длине первого вложенного массива (4), выводить `], [`. Работало не как хотел конечно

Comment: Спасибо, все отлично работает, как и хотел. Спасибо за оперативность

Answer (score 1):

Делов на 5 строчек:

```
$a = [[45, 16, 18, 72], [23, 8, 9, 36, 15, 36]];

$parts = [];
foreach ($a as $subarray) {
    $parts[] = '[ ' . implode(' ', $subarray) . ' ]';
}
echo '[' . implode(', ', $parts) . ']';
```

[Фидл](https://3v4l.org/ug0H2).

Comment: ))), капецкий, сдуреть можно) Спасибо большое, теперь два варианта есть решений, что может быть лучше. Спасибо за ссылку, довольно удобный ресурс. Не знал, что подобные есть для `PHP`. Думал для `HTML/CSS` и `JS`  есть подобное

Answer (score 0):

Вот так применил `implode()`, получилось лучше, чем хотел

Отдельное спасибо **[Ипатье'у](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/179379/%D0%98%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%D0%B5%D0%B2)** за идею попытаться хотя бы использовать `implode()`

Так же **[u_mulder'у](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178087/u-mulder)** за решение проблемы вывода `[ ]` для каждого вложенного массива

```
$twoDimensionalArrays = [[45, 16, 18, 72], [23, 8, 9, 36, 15, 36]];
            
foreach ($twoDimensionalArrays as $twoDimensionalArray) {
  $arrayString[] = '[' . implode(', ', $twoDimensionalArray) . ']';
}
echo "echo: \$twoDimensionalArrays = [" . implode(', ', $arrayString) . "];<br>";
```

Выводится следующий результат

`echo: $twoDimensionalArrays = [[45, 16, 18, 72], [23, 8, 9, 36, 15, 36]];`

Comment: После числа `36` нету запятой, это то, с чем не мог бороться, ответ постоянно игнорировался мной. Перед носом был